# How exactly do I install restful authentication plugin in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, restful-authentication

I'm very confused on this restful authentication plugin on rails 3. I tried to install the plugin using the following command. It tells me it's already installed, then I tried to use the `--force`  to reinstall this plugin it tells me that the plugin not found

So if the plugin is already installed why do I get error `Could not find generator authenticated` when I try to run the command `rails g authenticated user sessions --include-activation`

any ideas?

```
C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\blog>rails plugin install http://github.com
/technoweenie/restful-authentication.git restful_authentication
already installed: restful-authentication (http://github.com/technoweenie/restfu
l-authentication.git).  pass --force to reinstall
already installed: restful_authentication (restful_authentication).  pass --forc
e to reinstall

C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\blog>rails plugin install http://github.com
/technoweenie/restful-authentication.git restful_authentication --force
Plugin not found: ["http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication.git",
"restful_authentication"]

C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\blog>rails g authenticated user sessions --
include-activation
Could not find generator authenticated.
```

**Update:** here is the output after run `gem list`

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.1, 3.0.0)
actionpack (3.0.1, 3.0.0)
activemodel (3.0.1, 3.0.0)
activerecord (3.0.1, 3.0.0)
activeresource (3.0.1, 3.0.0)
activesupport (3.0.1, 3.0.0)
addressable (2.2.2)
arel (1.0.1)
bcrypt-ruby (2.1.2)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.3)
devise (1.1.3)
erubis (2.6.6)
faraday (0.4.6)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
git (1.2.5)
i18n (0.4.2, 0.4.1)
mail (2.2.9, 2.2.7)
mime-types (1.16)
minitest (1.6.0)
mongrel (1.2.0.pre2 x86-mingw32)
multi_json (0.0.4)
net-ldap (0.1.1)
nifty-generators (0.4.2, 0.4.1)
nokogiri (1.4.3.1 x86-mingw32)
oa-basic (0.1.5, 0.1.4)
oa-core (0.1.5, 0.1.4)
oa-enterprise (0.1.5, 0.1.4)
oa-oauth (0.1.5, 0.1.4)
oa-openid (0.1.5, 0.1.4)
oauth (0.4.3)
oauth2 (0.0.13)
omniauth (0.1.5, 0.1.4)
polyglot (0.3.1)
pyu-ruby-sasl (0.0.3.2)
rack (1.2.1)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-openid (1.1.2)
rack-test (0.5.6)
rails (3.0.1, 3.0.0)
railties (3.0.1, 3.0.0)
rake (0.8.7)
rdiscount (1.6.5)
rdoc (2.5.8)
rest-client (1.6.1)
ruby-openid (2.1.8)
ruby-openid-apps-discovery (1.2.0)
rubyntlm (0.1.1)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.1 x86-mingw32, 1.2.5 x86-mingw32)
thor (0.14.3)
treetop (1.4.8)
tzinfo (0.3.23)
warden (0.10.7)

Comment: run this command and put the output show us the out put. `gem list`

Comment: If you are using rails 3 you should be using bundler as that is how it manages gems. Shouldn't be doing gem install unless it's not with a rails like application

Comment: thanks @sam I updated my gem list files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restful authentication is no more 100% working in rails 3. It has some issues to fit in rails 3.x. Try using Authlogic or in fact "devise" should prove to be a great authentication system especially for Rails 3.x.I use devise for my apps and it works great !!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use gem "rails3-restful-authentication", "~> 3.0.1" for rails 3 support. I have done few patches to make it working with rails 3

Comment: Do you mean this [https://github.com/vatrai/rails3-restful-authentication] ? Because it is just one empty file.

Comment: ohh sorry. @Btuman I published the gem from local machine and never pushed the code. Its available now