# Rails: restful authentication setup help

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I downloaded the plugin from http://github.com/techweenie/restful-authentication.git

Then I run rails generate plugin authenticated user session

This is the result I got:

```
   create  vendor/plugins/authenticated
      create  vendor/plugins/authenticated/MIT-LICENSE
      create  vendor/plugins/authenticated/README
      create  vendor/plugins/authenticated/Rakefile
      create  vendor/plugins/authenticated/init.rb
      create  vendor/plugins/authenticated/install.rb
      create  vendor/plugins/authenticated/uninstall.rb
      create  vendor/plugins/authenticated/lib
      create  vendor/plugins/authenticated/lib/authenticated.rb
      invoke  test_unit
      inside    vendor/plugins/authenticated
      create      test
      create      test/authenticated_test.rb
      create      test/test_helper.rb
```

Then I tried to do rake db:migrate

But I got error that says rake tasks in restful-authentication/tasks/auth.rake are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead.

I am new to rails, tried looking online but things seem to be outdated. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

restful-authentication plugin is quite old and I think [not working with Rails 3.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038307/how-exactly-do-i-install-restful-authentication-plugin-in-rails-3)

As per the linked question, probably better to use something like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) or [Omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth).

~chris